# In PLSQL, How to fetch "User Tables" but not limited to Owner wise only, that have been created under different Schemas of different Users

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to fetch the list of tables against each user and owner of different schemas.

I tried this...

```sql
Select Owner, Object_Type from all_objects where Object_Type = "Table";
```

&

```sql
Select Owner, Table_Name from all_tables;
```

But I wanted tables user wise under its Owner.

Comment: Suggestion: Add the most relevant tags to your question to ensure it is seen by the domain experts for those tags. I removed the `datatables` tag and added some different tags instead. Your question has nothing to do with [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). I'm not convinced it has anything to do with PL/SQL, either (mentioned in the title) - maybe just Oracle's SQL.

Comment: As well as the standard [ask] guidelines, maybe the guidance in [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/12567365) is also worth a look.

Comment: I am not sure what "user wise under its owner" means.  Do you just want to add a `where owner = 'SomeUser'`?

Comment: What do you need finally? In Oracle, OWNER = USER = SCHEMA NAME

Comment: Just want to fetch the tables under each user as it is listed under option "Other Users" under any database connection.

Comment: @Vs_93: show us an example. Do you mean « ordered by user »?